# Using Terraform random_id to create multiple resources not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-storage, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to combine the usage of the random_id attribute with the count meta attribute to create multiple Azure storage accounts with unique names.

**Configuration code:**

```
# Create storage accounts

resource "random_id" "storage_account_name_unique" {
  byte_length = 8
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage" {
  count                    = "${var.storage_account_count}"
  name                     = "tfsta${lower(random_id.storage_account_name_unique.hex)}"
  resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  location                 = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  access_tier              = "Hot"
  account_replication_type = "${var.account_replication_type}"

  network_rules {
    ip_rules                   = ["127.0.0.1"]
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = ["${azurerm_subnet.subnet.id}"] 
  }

  tags = "${var.tags}"
  }
```

**Problems with this code:**

1. Terraform is only generating a single random_id and uses it for all of the storage account instances created during terraform apply operation.
2. Terraform is "fooled" into thinking it has created multiple storage accounts however only one storage account gets created

**Selected Terraform Apply output:**

This output shows that Terraform thinks it is creating three separate storage accounts with the same random_id. The plan is successfully applied but there is only one storage account created in Azure.

```
random_id.storage_account_name_unique: Creating...
  b64:         "" => "<computed>"
  b64_std:     "" => "<computed>"
  b64_url:     "" => "<computed>"
  byte_length: "" => "8"
  dec:         "" => "<computed>"
  hex:         "" => "<computed>"
random_id.storage_account_name_unique: Creation complete after 0s (ID: kYl9WvpTSso)

azurerm_storage_account.storage[2]: Creating...
  access_tier:                                           "" => "Hot"
  account_encryption_source:                             "" => "Microsoft.Storage"
  account_kind:                                          "" => "StorageV2"
  account_replication_type:                              "" => "LRS"
  account_tier:                                          "" => "Standard"
  enable_blob_encryption:                                "" => "true"
  enable_file_encryption:                                "" => "true"
  identity.#:                                            "" => "<computed>"
  location:                                              "" => "westus2"
  name:                                                  "" => "tfsta91897d5afa534aca"
  network_rules.#:                                       "" => "1"
  network_rules.0.bypass.#:                              "" => "<computed>"
  network_rules.0.ip_rules.#:                            "" => "1"
  network_rules.0.ip_rules.3619153832:                   "" => "127.0.0.1"
  network_rules.0.virtual_network_subnet_ids.#:          "" => "1"
  network_rules.0.virtual_network_subnet_ids.3223410521: "" => "/subscriptions/f6d69ee2-34d5-4ca8-a143-7a2fc1aeca55/resourceGroups/hdi-dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/hdi-dev-vnet/subnets/hdinsight"
  primary_access_key:                                    "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  primary_blob_connection_string:                        "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  primary_blob_endpoint:                                 "" => "<computed>"
  primary_connection_string:                             "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  primary_file_endpoint:                                 "" => "<computed>"
  primary_location:                                      "" => "<computed>"
  primary_queue_endpoint:                                "" => "<computed>"
  primary_table_endpoint:                                "" => "<computed>"
  resource_group_name:                                   "" => "hdi-dev-rg"
  secondary_access_key:                                  "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  secondary_blob_connection_string:                      "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  secondary_blob_endpoint:                               "" => "<computed>"
  secondary_connection_string:                           "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  secondary_location:                                    "" => "<computed>"
  secondary_queue_endpoint:                              "" => "<computed>"
  secondary_table_endpoint:                              "" => "<computed>"
  tags.%:                                                "" => "3"
  tags.costcenter:                                       "" => "Unknown"
  tags.environment:                                      "" => "Dev"
  tags.project:                                          "" => "Unknown"
azurerm_storage_account.storage[1]: Creating...
  access_tier:                                           "" => "Hot"
  account_encryption_source:                             "" => "Microsoft.Storage"
  account_kind:                                          "" => "StorageV2"
  account_replication_type:                              "" => "LRS"
  account_tier:                                          "" => "Standard"
  enable_blob_encryption:                                "" => "true"
  enable_file_encryption:                                "" => "true"
  identity.#:                                            "" => "<computed>"
  location:                                              "" => "westus2"
  name:                                                  "" => "tfsta91897d5afa534aca"
  network_rules.#:                                       "" => "1"
  network_rules.0.bypass.#:                              "" => "<computed>"
  network_rules.0.ip_rules.#:                            "" => "1"
  network_rules.0.ip_rules.3619153832:                   "" => "127.0.0.1"
  network_rules.0.virtual_network_subnet_ids.#:          "" => "1"
  network_rules.0.virtual_network_subnet_ids.3223410521: "" => "/subscriptions/f6d69ee2-34d5-4ca8-a143-7a2fc1aeca55/resourceGroups/hdi-dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/hdi-dev-vnet/subnets/hdinsight"
  primary_access_key:                                    "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  primary_blob_connection_string:                        "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  primary_blob_endpoint:                                 "" => "<computed>"
  primary_connection_string:                             "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  primary_file_endpoint:                                 "" => "<computed>"
  primary_location:                                      "" => "<computed>"
  primary_queue_endpoint:                                "" => "<computed>"
  primary_table_endpoint:                                "" => "<computed>"
  resource_group_name:                                   "" => "hdi-dev-rg"
  secondary_access_key:                                  "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  secondary_blob_connection_string:                      "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  secondary_blob_endpoint:                               "" => "<computed>"
  secondary_connection_string:                           "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  secondary_location:                                    "" => "<computed>"
  secondary_queue_endpoint:                              "" => "<computed>"
  secondary_table_endpoint:                              "" => "<computed>"
  tags.%:                                                "" => "3"
  tags.costcenter:                                       "" => "Unknown"
  tags.environment:                                      "" => "Dev"
  tags.project:                                          "" => "Unknown"
azurerm_storage_account.storage[0]: Creating...
  access_tier:                                           "" => "Hot"
  account_encryption_source:                             "" => "Microsoft.Storage"
  account_kind:                                          "" => "StorageV2"
  account_replication_type:                              "" => "LRS"
  account_tier:                                          "" => "Standard"
  enable_blob_encryption:                                "" => "true"
  enable_file_encryption:                                "" => "true"
  identity.#:                                            "" => "<computed>"
  location:                                              "" => "westus2"
  name:                                                  "" => "tfsta91897d5afa534aca"
  network_rules.#:                                       "" => "1"
  network_rules.0.bypass.#:                              "" => "<computed>"
  network_rules.0.ip_rules.#:                            "" => "1"
  network_rules.0.ip_rules.3619153832:                   "" => "127.0.0.1"
  network_rules.0.virtual_network_subnet_ids.#:          "" => "1"
  network_rules.0.virtual_network_subnet_ids.3223410521: "" => "/subscriptions/f6d69ee2-34d5-4ca8-a143-7a2fc1aeca55/resourceGroups/hdi-dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/hdi-dev-vnet/subnets/hdinsight"
  primary_access_key:                                    "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  primary_blob_connection_string:                        "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  primary_blob_endpoint:                                 "" => "<computed>"
  primary_connection_string:                             "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  primary_file_endpoint:                                 "" => "<computed>"
  primary_location:                                      "" => "<computed>"
  primary_queue_endpoint:                                "" => "<computed>"
  primary_table_endpoint:                                "" => "<computed>"
  resource_group_name:                                   "" => "hdi-dev-rg"
  secondary_access_key:                                  "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  secondary_blob_connection_string:                      "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  secondary_blob_endpoint:                               "" => "<computed>"
  secondary_connection_string:                           "<sensitive>" => "<sensitive>"
  secondary_location:                                    "" => "<computed>"
  secondary_queue_endpoint:                              "" => "<computed>"
  secondary_table_endpoint:                              "" => "<computed>"
  tags.%:                                                "" => "3"
  tags.costcenter:                                       "" => "Unknown"
  tags.environment:                                      "" => "Dev"
  tags.project:                                          "" => "Unknown"
azurerm_storage_account.storage[0]: Creation complete after 21s (ID: /subscriptions/f6d69ee2-34d5-4ca8-a143-.../storageAccounts/tfsta91897d5afa534aca)
azurerm_storage_account.storage[2]: Creation complete after 22s (ID: /subscriptions/f6d69ee2-34d5-4ca8-a143-.../storageAccounts/tfsta91897d5afa534aca)
azurerm_storage_account.storage[1]: Creation complete after 23s (ID: /subscriptions/f6d69ee2-34d5-4ca8-a143-.../storageAccounts/tfsta91897d5afa534aca)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue here is your use of the random string, you've only made one string and reused the same string in each name. 
If you want to have a random string element as part of your storage account name you'll need multiple random strings. The sample below demonstrates using and creating multiple random strings in a resource.

```
resource "random_id" "storage_account_name_unique" {
  count = "${var.storage_account_count}"
  byte_length = 8
}

output "random"{
value=["${random_id.storage_account_name_unique.*.hex}"]
}

provider "random" {
  version="2.0"
}

resource "null_resource" "echo" {
  count = "${var.storage_account_count}"
  provisioner "local-exec" {     
    command = 
      "echo ${element(random_id.storage_account_name_unique.*.hex, count.index)}"
  }
}
```

This gives you:

```
null_resource.echo[0]: Creating...
null_resource.echo[1]: Creating...
null_resource.echo[0]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.echo[1]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.echo[1] (local-exec): Executing: ["cmd" "/C" "echo e5ddcf9fb82798f2"]
null_resource.echo[0] (local-exec): Executing: ["cmd" "/C" "echo ceb231a41c8cdb24"]
null_resource.echo[1] (local-exec): e5ddcf9fb82798f2
null_resource.echo[0] (local-exec): ceb231a41c8cdb24
null_resource.echo[1]: Creation complete after 0s (ID: 3289535031294242492)
null_resource.echo[0]: Creation complete after 0s (ID: 4611439113584915035)

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

random = [
    ceb231a41c8cdb24,
    e5ddcf9fb82798f2
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the same no matter use the Terraform or the Azure REST API to create the storage account. It shows in the [Azure REST API - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/create):

> Asynchronously creates a new storage account with the specified
>   parameters. If an account is already created and a subsequent create
>   request is issued with different properties, the account properties
>   will be updated. If an account is already created and a subsequent
>   create or update request is issued with the exact same set of
>   properties, the request will succeed.

So when it creates the first storage account, the operation act as usual. But the subsequent creation with the same name would follow the rule above. Finally, only one storage account is retained with the one name. If you want to create more than one storage account, you should use different names.

Comment: Super helpful, explains the behavior of Terraform with creating multiple storage accounts with the same name.

Comment: @RogerDoherty So you can upvote it or mark it as the answer.